# Tkinter dialog to open file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, dialog

I have a tool where it is possible to open a dialog with a button. There is a button for a file dialog and a button for directory dialog. I was wondering if there is something in Tkinter where I can have one button that opens a dialog that will except a file or a directory. So I want to go from two different dialogs to just one. Is there something like this in Tkinter or is it possible to create this? Maybe something like an extension filter but then you can select whether you want to choose a file or directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible with the standard dialogs from `tkinter.filedialog` but you can make your own dialog with a `ttk.Treeview`. I made my own [filebrowser](https://github.com/j4321/tkFileBrowser) for Linux and you can probably adapt it to do what you want though I had separated file selection from directory selection.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and will report back if I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it in a different way. The only downside is that I can't select multiple files or folders, but other than that it does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Here is the code I used:

```
mydocs_pidl = shell.SHGetFolderLocation(0, shellcon.CSIDL_DRIVES, 0, 0)
    pidl, display_name, image_list = shell.SHBrowseForFolder(
        win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(),
        mydocs_pidl,
        "Select a file or folder",
        shellcon.BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES,
        None,
        None
    )

if (pidl, display_name, image_list) == (None, None, None):
    print("No file or directory selected!")
else:
    path = str(shell.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl))
    print(path)
```